# MySQL error #1064 when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are a bunch of questions with this subject but I haven't found my mistake here. I've just started learning SQL.

My query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `quizid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `result` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `IP` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `ts` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)' at line 6
```

I know the answer must be easy to spot by the right eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timestamp` *does not* accept length in `CREATE TABLE` clause

Answer (score 3):

`timestamp` accepts length but upto `6` precision numbers. But then you need not specify length for `timestamp`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html does it? It's not specified in the `CREATE TABLE` syntax :-S

Comment: Tried with `TIMESTAMP(2)`. It was executed as if the length wasn't specified at all

Comment: you can if you specify the default value as `none` but then that doesn't make much of sense..